# Recursión - Función con objeto y número como parámetro - Secuencia inventada (fórmula)

Tags: funciones, objeto, parametros

```js
function secuenciaWisu(obj,n) {
      if(n<0)return null;
      if(n===0)return  obj.first;
      if(n===1)return Object.keys(obj).length;
      if(n>=3){
        return secuenciaWisu(n-1)*secuenciaWisu(n-2)-secuenciaWisu(n-2);
      }
    }
```

Hola. Alguien me ayuda con este ejercicio de recursión ya que me retorna un NaN cuando invoco la secuencia.
Donde las primeras dos posiciones son dadas por el parametro recibidos y a partir de la siguiente se calcula como la multiplicación de los 2 números anteriores restados al número anterior.
object es un objeto del cual debemos obtener f(0) y f(1) siguiendo la siguiente lógica:
f(0) será el valor de la propiedad llamada 'first'
f(1) será un número igual a la cantidad de propiedades de obj

Comment: Por favor, no pongas código en los comentarios. Puedes editar tu pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece a pie de pregunta y agregar la información que falta.  Aún así, **aquí no realizamos tareas**. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender bien como funciona este sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas:

1: La función `secuenciaWisu` no retorna nada en el caso de que `n == 2`

```
if(n<0)return null;
if(n===0)return  obj.first;
if(n===1)return Object.keys(obj).length;
if(n>=3){ //Aquí debería ser n >= 2 o, aún mejor, elimina este último if puesto que no hay ningún otro caso
    return secuenciaWisu(n-1)*secuenciaWisu(n-2)-secuenciaWisu(n-2);
}
```

2: No estás pasando el parametro `obj` cuando vuelves a llamar a la función `secuenciaWisu`

```
return secuenciaWisu(n-1)*secuenciaWisu(n-2)-secuenciaWisu(n-2);

//Debería ser:

return secuenciaWisu(obj, n-1)*secuenciaWisu(obj, n-2)-secuenciaWisu(obj, n-2);
```

3: Se puede evitar ejecutar `secuenciaWisu(obj, n-2)` dos veces si extraes el factor común:

```
return secuenciaWisu(obj, n-1)*secuenciaWisu(obj, n-2)-secuenciaWisu(obj, n-2);

//f(n-1) * f(n-2) - f(n-2) = f(n-2) * (f(n-1) - 1)

return secuenciaWisu(obj, n-2) * (secuenciaWisu(obj, n-1) - 1);
```

Y un detalle más. La pregunta dice "se calcula como la multiplicación de los 2 números anteriores restados al número anterior".

Más alla del pequeño error gramatical (sería "menos el número anterior") yo interpretaría esto como `f(n-1) * f(n-2) - f(n-1)`, no como `f(n-1) * f(n-2) - f(n-2)`

Comment: Gracias Fedex, me super sirvió. no te agradecí antes porque no sabía como comentar después de la respuesta. te agradezco.